# CSS won't transition opacity

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, transition, opacity

What I want to do in the bigger picture is delay the popup for a few seconds after page-load using pure `CSS`. I've decided the best way to do that is by transitioning the opacity, then using transition-delay to delay it for a few seconds.

My problem is that transition doesn't work and won't delay the popup (nor the dark overlay).

1. Why is that and how can I fix it?
2. If it's not possible, is there another way to delay the popup for a few seconds?

```css
hr {
  clear: both;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  border: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}

#css-only-modals {
  position: fixed;
  pointer-events: none;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 10000000;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  height: 100%;
}

#css-only-modals:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: -0.25em;
}

.css-only-modal-check {
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.css-only-modal-check:checked~.css-only-modal {
  /* FOR TRANSITION */
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 3s;
  /*NOT WORKING */
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.css-only-modal {
  width: 360px;
  background: #FFF;
  z-index: 1;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  pointer-events: auto;
  padding: 25px;
  text-align: right;
  border-radius: 4px;
  white-space: normal;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.css-only-modal h2 {
  text-align: left;
  color: #1A1A1C;
}

.css-only-modal p {
  text-align: left;
}

.css-only-modal-close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  right: 25px;
}

.css-only-modal-check {
  display: none;
}

.css-only-modal-check:checked~#screen-shade {
  /* FOR TRANSITION */
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition: opacity 3s;
  /*NOT WORKING */
  pointer-events: auto;
}

#screen-shade {
  opacity: 0;
  background: #000;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: opacity 0.8s;
}

.stripe>.container>p,
.stripe>.container>ul {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 35px;
  margin: 0;
}

#nav-spacer {
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
}

.stripe {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.css-only-modal-btn {
  background-color: #BD2C15;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px 18px;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
}

.css-only-modal-btn:hover {
  color: #BD2C15;
  background-color: transparent;
  outline: 2px solid #BD2C15;
  transition: background-color 0.5s, color 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<label for="modal1">
  <div id="css-only-modals">
    <input id="modal1" class="css-only-modal-check" type="checkbox" checked/>
    <div class="css-only-modal">
      <label for="modal1" class="css-only-modal-close"><i class="fa fa-times fa-2x"></i></label>
      <h2>Referral</h2>
      <hr />
      <p>Refer a customer, email me and receive a 25% commission. <br> Earn up to 1225$ from a single referral!</p>
      <hr />
      <label for="modal1" class="css-only-modal-btn">NICE!</label>
    </div>
    <div id="screen-shade"></div>
  </div>
</label>
```

In the `CSS` I created two comments "FOR TRANSITION". They mark the opacities I want to transition.

Comment: the `transition` should be always set, not just when something been checked then you set the `transition`.

Comment: I need it to transition after :checked activates, it's the way the HTML popup is made. If I put it to be always set, not just when it's checked, I can't close the popup. Or maybe I'm misunderstanding something?

Comment: yeah, you misunderstanding the `transition` property. Read this [MDN Article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions) to learn more

Comment: It's possible using css animations

Comment: I'll try that, thanks

Comment: The `transition` property should be defined under `.css-only-modal`, not  `.css-only-modal-check:checked ~ .css-only-modal`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the transition on your initial element.

```
.css-only-modal-check {
    pointer-events: auto;
}


.css-only-modal-check ~ .css-only-modal {
    /* FOR TRANSITION */
    transition: opacity 3s; 
}

.css-only-modal-check:checked ~ .css-only-modal {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: auto;
}

.css-only-modal {
    width: 360px;
    background: #FFF;
    z-index: 1;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    pointer-events: auto;
    padding: 25px;
    text-align: right;
    border-radius: 4px;
    white-space: normal;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: I copied and replaced my code with your code, it doesn't seem to work. Have you tried it? Maybe I made a mistake

Edit: It transitions the fade-out it after I click the "Nice!" button. I want to transition the fade-in

Comment: Let me make a quick fiddle and i'll take a look. give me 5 min

Comment: @JamesCurtis, i've created that codepen. So the only thing wich was weird is that the input is checked by default. So you have to check or uncheck the box to actually see the changes happening. I removed the display: none from your input and if i check or uncheck it it works fine.  -> https://codepen.io/mblmarlon/pen/RwPrrOR

Comment: I see, thanks. Is there a way I can delay checking the button after page load? What I mean is that the button checks itself after 3-4 seconds after page-load. If I can do that, the problem is solved. By the way, this insight has helped me immensely.

Comment: Well if you don't need a checkbox anyways you don't neccesarily need it. You can add a class to your modal like window.onload... and then add class such as 'active' and if modal.active then make oacity 1, ... (you can add a delay to that too bot function and animation-delay). If you then click the button you might want to remove the active class again.

Comment: I'm quite sure you can check an input field via JS tho. again window.onload... and then something like getElementById => value = checked. But i'd prefere setting classes since you're checkbox doesn't really have a function

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure to keep the transition always set, only change the opacity to 0 on ~checked.

Also transition-delay must be underneath the transition.
here is the full modified code

```
.css-only-modal-check {
    pointer-events: auto;
}


.css-only-modal-check ~ .css-only-modal {
    /* FOR TRANSITION */
    transition: opacity 3s; 
}

.css-only-modal-check:checked ~ .css-only-modal {
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: auto;
}

.css-only-modal {
    width: 360px;
    background: #FFF;
    z-index: 1;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    pointer-events: auto;
    padding: 25px;
    text-align: right;
    border-radius: 4px;
    white-space: normal;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    /*opacity: 0;*/
    transition: opacity 3s; 
    transition-delay:2s;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: When I set the :checked to how you said it should be, the popup just stays at 0 opacity on page-load.

Here's the code:

.css-only-modal-check:checked ~ .css-only-modal {

    /* FOR TRANSITION */

    transition:3s;

    opacity:0;

    pointer-events: auto;

}

Comment: you need to remove opacity:0 from " .css-only-modal "
because that set's it by default to 0. and by default it should be one and only when ~checked it should be 0.

Comment: @Gershomcheck the rest of the answer